# CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable always return true

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ping

My Xamarin iOS APP wants to check the Internet connectivity through **CrossConnectivity** API.
I found that the **"resp"** always returns **true** whether Internet is worked or not.
(even if I unplugged the router, the API returns "**true**")

```
bool resp = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable("google.com", 5000); //resp = true
```

Otherwise, I change the host to "8.8.8.8", the API always returns **false** even if the Internet is worked.

```
bool resp = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable("8.8.8.8", 5000); //resp=false
```

Is anyone know how to fix this issue?

Xaml.Plugin.Connectivity(Version:3.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me the easiest way to check this is to use XF essential's Connectivity plugin:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
    // Connection to internet is available
}
```

**Limitations:**

> It is important to note that it is possible that Internet is reported by NetworkAccess but full access to the web is not available. Due to how connectivity works on each platform it can only guarantee that a connection is available. For instance the device may be connected to a Wi-Fi network, but the router is disconnected from the internet. In this instance Internet may be reported, but an active connection is not available.